# ssis: How to format output value to have 0.0000 in front

Tags: ssis

I have an SQL statement which selected value like 0.0000 from the tables.

However when the file is generated in SSIS, the value become .000.

Is there anyway to format the value to be like 0.000? If need to write a script component how to go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the value to string before writing it to a file. Assume A is the name of the field, then the derived column will be

```
A < 1 ? "0" + (DT_STR,10,1252)A : (DT_STR,10,1252)A
```